# Is there an easy way to make a horizontally paged UIScrollView wrap around?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIScrollView. Any thoughts on implementing “infinite” scroll/zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493950/uiscrollview-any-thoughts-on-implementing-infinite-scroll-zoom)

I notice that in the stocks application, the small graph wraps around, eg: when you get to the end of the scroll view and swipe right again, you go back to the beginning. Before I go ahead and code this myself is there an easy way to do this in the SDK? I can't find any properties or methods that would enable that?

I have a paged UIScrollView that scrolls horizontally, pretty much exactly like the stocks application one does.

Comment: I want to know this too. They do it in iWork on the iPad...

Is there a way for me to add another bounty :P?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there's a property to do this.  I've faked it by adding an extra page on each end, so with for a 5 page UIScrollView you'd set the contentSize for 7 pages and load them like this:

5 1 2 3 4 5 1

Then in scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:, check if you're at either end and if so call scrollRectToVisible:animated: on your UIScrollView to jump it to the "real" page 1 or 5 position (without animation).

Comment: Hi John!
I try that, and it woks fine. What about if want to show 3 images at the time and have the same effect?? Can you help me??