# iOS Horizontal Menu w ScrollView

Tags: ios, paging, horizontalscrollview

I want to make a horizontal scrollview menu like top of picture at bottom.(NEWSLETTER, CITY, WOMEN etc.) I'm researching for two days. But i didn't find a solution for my problem.

This menu must can loopable. Selected item will be at center of screen. And have a effect like paging. But when i pagingEnabled on scroll view it's making pages for every frames. I want a page each menu item.

Someone can give me some idea?

Thank you.

[image: This app called Gild in AppStore]

Answer (score 0):

There's some decent options out there for wrapping the content in your UIScrollView. Check out: [Make UIScrollView wrap around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071623/make-uiscrollview-wrap-around).

Also take a look at this github project: https://github.com/jonah-carbonfive/WrappingScrollView