# How to make a UIScrollView apply a transformation to a subview based on its position?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I would like to make a UIScrollView in which items appear to wrap around a tube, like a UIPickerView. How can this be achieved?

Comment: can you check if this will help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3071623/make-uiscrollview-wrap-around

Comment: Is paging enable doesn't help ?