# How to make uiscrollview's content in cycle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiscrollview, cycle

I want to make content of uiscrollview to be run in cycle. In other words, I mean when we move to the top and try to access the previous then the last content of the scrollview should be displayed AND if I am on last content and try to access next then first content should be display.
I want to achieve infinite scrolling in uiscrollview

Is it possible in objective-c iPhone?

Please tell me any tutorial link or the code to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UIScrollView. Any thoughts on implementing "infinite" scroll/zoom?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493950/uiscrollview-any-thoughts-on-implementing-infinite-scroll-zoom)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer of my question here http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

It helped me in my project

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [WWDC videos](http://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/index.php) on UIScrollView.

Comment: AFAIK sample code used in videos is provided on Apple's Developer website.