# Loop a UIScrollviw with ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a UIScrollView with loop that contains a collection of ViewControllers. The answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383849/loop-an-uiscrollview) shows the code that is the basis for what I'm trying to do. It uses images instead of viewControllers.

I've managed to get the all the viewControllers loaded (4) and displaying but the first view which is a duplicate of the last viewController is blank. I've tried creating a copy of this viewController and adding it to the array but this messes up the transition / count. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

Simply add a copy of the viewController (copyWithZone) to the array then create another copy of the two viewControllers for the first and last frame. I had done this only for the first and last frames not the array.