# how to scroll scrollview horizontally

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone.I need to scroll scrollview horizontally instead of vertical.Is it possible to scroll horizontally.If it possible pls post link  consist sample example.Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use following code

[myscrollview addSubview:imgButton];

x = frame.origin.x;
y = frame.origin.y+80;

[myscrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(x,y)];

in that each time you add a new button/Image increase content size Y position and also make set scroll vertical false.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383849/loop-an-uiscrollview) is the link to your question.

Comment: pls post some sample example link

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer you without a concrete example. In general, the scrolling directions of a UIScrollView are defined by it's "contentSize" property. So if you have a label (myLabel) which is wider than your scrollView (myScrollview) you could write this:

```
myScrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myLabel.frame.size.width, myScrollview.frame.size.height);
//Next line is rather optional, should be already set by default
myScrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
```

Comment: i did n't get it pls post any link consist sample example on it

Answer (score 0):

If you want an example, here [the sample codes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007795) are.
As Phlibbo said, the contentSize of scrollView will decide the direction of that.